# Ingesting data from external table into ADX

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

Let's say I already have an external table of kind ADL created for some other purpose but now I want to also ingest data pointed to by the external table to one of the native Kusto tables. Is there a command to do that in ADX? Logically it is like reusing external table definition for some other purpose, instead of specifying the same end point information again. Also, if it helps, I would like add that this will be periodic refresh (to keep native table in sync with external table) , basically it's not a one time thing.

This is how my external table definition looks like:-

```
.create external table my_external_table
(      
    col1:string,
    col2:string,
    col3:string
) 
kind=adl
partition by (myvirtualcol:string) 
dataformat=orc
(
  h@'abfss://<storage-end-point>;<MaskedAccessKey>'
)
```

I can always do the following:-

```
.set-or-replace async my_native_table <| external_table('my_external_table')
```

But I would like to know if there is any special way to handle this kind of situation other than this obvious method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if** the amount of data in the external table is small enough (say, up to a few GBs) - you can use `.set-or-append`.

for example:

```
.set-or-append MyTable <|
    external_table('MyExternalTable')
```

**otherwise**, it's best to:

1. queue existing files for ingestion from the container(s) (e.g. using tools like `LightIngest`)
2. setup a [data connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/create-event-grid-connection?tabs=portal-adx%2Cazure-blob-storage) for ingestion of any newly written file to the container(s)

Comment: data is not small , and when I tried ingesting by querying the external table directly, I got this error:-  There is not enough space on the disk

Comment: does the "not enough space on the disk" error mean there is no enough space allotted for the specific database or specific cluster ? Is there any quick cluster config change that will overcome this ?

Comment: sounds like you missed the **"if"** and **"otherwise"** in the answer :) the error you're seeing is likely indicates that the amount of data that is being downloaded from the external table can't fit on the cluster's nodes' local disks. that's not a setting at the database level that you can override, but depending on which SKU you're running with, you can scale up (to a SKU with larger disk size). if you need further assistance with troubleshooting an incident, please open a support ticket for your resource